# Use native Google Maps database to Store Locator

Tags: maps, store

Is there any way to use Google maps native markers instead of having to create my own database?

Can't find any article talking about this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Places API: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

But why not create your own to ensure accuracy?

Comment: in fact, this is a good point. But, I need to map thousands of points, the same that we see on google maps.
On that case, what is the better approach.
1. Use the google maps markers.
2. Import the markers of google maps to my database and use it. (On this case, how could I do this importation?

Comment: I would use theirs directly: 1) Google doesn't permit caching (duplicating to your DB) and 2) if you copy, you'll have to sync periodically, which may be more work that just using their data. Also, when you say "marker" you just mean "location," correct? not the inverted tear drop that indicates a location?